# Preloading web assets: load less then the full size of the file

Tags: php, javascript, asp.net

You (me, we, everyone etc) no doubt aware of methods to load and preload assets on a site. But I was wondering if it's at all possible, either server or client side, to partially load an assets.

Let's say I have 10 images on my site, all 500kb.

But these images are not immediately viewable until a user triggered event.

Is it at all possible, to load say, 200kb of each image on load, and then load the remaining 300kb when needed?

I don't need info on preloading, as it been well documented in many places, just if partial loadin of assets is something anyone has tried and achieved

Thank for any ideas

Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly perform a partial load where you only load X out of your 500 images.  However, it seems highly unlikely that loading only 200K of a 500K file would be useful on the web -- particularly with images.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you're looking for, but there are lazy-loading plugins out there that will delay loading of images until the user scrolls them into view.

Most of the frameworks out there currently have a plugin for them ([jQuery's Lazy Loading](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) plugin by Mike Tuupola used to not work correctly, but it seems he's done some work on it).  I've also found examples for [MooTools](http://davidwalsh.name/mootools-lazyload), [Prototype](http://www.bram.us/projects/js_bramus/lazierload/) and [YUI](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/imageloader/)